# Правильно ли составлена структура БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, uml

Основные функции системы это заполнение/редактирование/удаление таблиц БД и поиск по БД.

Все таблицы, кроме status и scientist являются, как бы, справочниками - заполняются отдельно от "Scientist".

Например "summary_scientific_work" - хранит в себе ID научной работы и соответствующего ей ученого.

Подтаблицы таблицы Education разбиты так, чтобы не допустить опечаток для последующего поиска по БД.

Что можно упростить/улучшить придерживаясь всех НФ?

[image: Структура БД]

Comment: Что бы сказать что в ней можно поправить надо полностью понимать исходную задачу и все технологические процессы при которых будет использоваться система. Я вот например совершенно не понимаю, почему при образовании указан университет, но не указана специальность на которую обучался данный специалист

Comment: не описана предметная область от слова совсем. поменяйте нотацию хоть на такую http://i.imgur.com/Hz7lyyU.jpg чтобы были видны внешние ключи. работы и исследования суть разные вещи? вообще можно исходить от 4 объектов - ученый, образование, научные работы, всякая дичь вроде учителей (накуя?).

Comment: @des1roer Работы и исследования наверняка разные вещи. под работами обычно публикуемые материалы понимаются. Они могут быть основаны на нескольких исследованиях, но связь с исследованиями ТС видимо не нужна. По повду учителей и т.п. раз они есть - значит они нужны ТС или заказчику, потому как есть в его предметной области. так что не нам судить о их необходимости

Comment: @ZhiV В общем я не вижу у вас в модели никакого криминала, все что предлагают на данный момент в ответах - ухудшает модель. Улучшать непонятно куда. Единственное - длинная цепочка университеты-департаменты-специальности напрягает. Возможно часть надо оформлять в виде дерева, кто его знает какой глубины иерархия еще там появится. Без понимания предметной области больше сказать невозможно

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

образование наверно логично сделать одной таблицей с внешними ключами на справочники (факультет, город, название)

под справочник не обязательно создавать 100500 таблиц, если там будет 3 строки (ПТУ, универ, школа).

можно как в таблице work_all сделать поле под предка (правда не знаю насколько академически это правильно, но в реальной жизни работает на ура)

что-то суммарное не имеет права на жизнь. это дублирование и нарушение принципов нормализации. все суммарное отдается с помощью представлений

Comment: Вы почему то выбросили таблицу образование, так что если у человека два высших - то уложить невозможно. Судя по модели ТС под университетом понимаются конкретные образовательные учреждения. Так что name не надо из него выносить потому как там значения "МГУ", "МГТУ" и т.п. А вы это имя почему то преобразовали в справочник видов образовательных учреждений.

Comment: человек может дважды закончить мгу - на дневном и на вечернем.

Comment: и это именно справочник как в вк http://i.imgur.com/InhRLeD.jpg

Comment: Теперь понял. Но тогда не ясно почему факультеты отдельно от институтов. Обычно же говорят "Закончил факультет пчеловодства машиностроительного института", т.е. всегда есть связь факультета с его институтом. Но ТС почему то считает, что ему для задачи достаточно просто института. А факультеты и т.п. просто как справичник "что вообще бывает в данном институте" висят

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не знаю объем данных, который будет хранится в таблице `scientist`, поэтому моё предложение возможно будет плохим с точки зрения производительности.
Но я бы сделал поле `teacher_id` внутри таблицы `scientist`. И естественно избавился бы этим от таблицы `teacher_pupil`.

Comment: Раз такая таблица создана, то скорее всего у одного специалиста может быть несколько учителей, а при вашем предложении это хранить будет невозможно

Comment: @Mike Да. Не учел множественные связи.